# What is the purpose of the square zigzag trace on BLDC PCBs?

Tags: pcb-design, brushless-dc-motor

I have a couple of 24V motors from a laser printers/photocopiers they both have a square zigzag trace on the PCB around the circumference of the stator. This trace is covered by the edge of the rotor magnets when the motor is assembled. What is its purpose?

I think the disassembled motor in the image is from a photocopier.

[image: PCB and stator of BLDC]

Comment: It's called `serpentine` (not `zigzag`) and it generates a sine wave with an amplitude and frequency that directly relates to motor speed. Look up terms like `flutter` and `jitter` and `reluctance` along with `serpentine` and `speed control`, for example. Hall sensors can also be used. But this is cheaper and perhaps less likely to fail over time. I'll see if I can find a reference.

Comment: Ah. Yes. [Look here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809301215_Texas-Instruments-DRV8308RHAR_C181641.pdf). Looks like I don't need to write anything! Anytime you see something like that near coils you should imagine the magnetic fields generated and how they interact with such traces.

Comment: Just FYI, you need no experience to draw from for something like this. Just the basics of physical theory makes this instantly obvious. (Also take note of the curved trace between the motor coils and the serpentine trace.) When I first saw these, they were also totally new to me as well. And I was also similarly curious. But I instantly knew what to search for because physics is physics and there could be little else that would make sense. I recall quickly finding something akin to the link I just found, above. But good question!! +1!

Comment: I think that it is part of a `resolver` for sensing the angular position of the rotor